# Control tertiary jar access to shaded classes

Tags: gradle, gradle-shadow-plugin

I have a project that has two dependencies that both have tertiary dependencies on different version of Guava; 14.0.1 and 18

14.0.1 is available as provided, and I have bundled version 18 in my uber jar and shaded it to relocate the problematic package `com.google.common.collect` to `shaded.com.google.common.collect`, and verified this with `jar -tf`

This is where my understanding of shading jars gets hazy - how are my two dependant jars that need Guava supposed to know which package to use out of the standard and shaded ones?

I'm using gradle to build my project, with the `com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3` plugin.